# When I convert data between tensor of Pytorch and numpy, when do they share memory and when do they use new memory?

Tags: numpy, memory, pytorch, tensor

I write two pieces of programm.

The first is:

```
import torch

c = torch.ones(3, 3)
d = c.numpy()
e = torch.tensor(d)
e[0, 0] = 100.0
print(c)
print(d)
```

output is:

```
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

Another piece of programm:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((3, 3))
b = torch.tensor(a)
b[0, 0] = 100
print(a)
print(b)

c = torch.ones(3, 3)
d = c.numpy()
d[0, 0] = 100.0
print(c)
print(d)
```

Output is:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
tensor([[100.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.]], dtype=torch.float64)
tensor([[100.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.],
        [  1.,   1.,   1.]])
[[100.   1.   1.]
 [  1.   1.   1.]
 [  1.   1.   1.]]
```

I don't know when and why the "1"(first col, first row) change to "100", and when and why it not.

Comment: According to docs, [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html#torch.tensor) -- "Constructs a tensor ... by copying data." If you want the data to be shared, use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html#torch.from_numpy).

Comment: The result of [`Tensor.numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.numpy.html#torch.Tensor.numpy) will cause the memory to be shared (if possible, otherwise it will fail, if I read the docs correctly), unless you set `force` to `True`, in which case a copy may be made when needed.